# unittest internal function in django

Tags: django, unit-testing

I started using unitest in my django projects, and am interested in testing `process_email()`. Since I am testing email functionality, I am interested in testing the `parse_email()` function. This code below is command line management function (i.e. I do python manage.py process_email).

**How do I call `parse_email()` in my unittest?**

Since this code is in a file called `somemodel/management/commands/process_email.py`, only `process_email()` is visible. Subsequently, `call_command('parse_email', mail.outbox[1].body, interactive=False)` will not work since only `process_email()` is visible.

```
def process_email():
    server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(settings.EMAIL_HOST,993)
    server.login(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
    server.select('INBOX')
    status, data = server.search(None, 'NOT', 'DELETED')

    if data:
        msgnums = data[0].split()

        for num in msgnums:
            status, data = server.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            valid = parse_email(data[0][1])
            print "valid is ", valid
            #            if not valid:
            server.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')

    server.expunge()
    server.close()
    server.logout()

def parse_email(message):
    # 'message' must be an RFC822 formatted message.
    pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        msg = message   
        message = email.message_from_string(msg)
        subject = message.get('subject', _('Created from e-mail'))
        subject = decode_mail_headers(decodeUnknown(message.get_charset(), subject))
        subject = subject.replace("Re: ", "").replace("Fw: ", "").replace("RE: ", "").replace("FW: ", "").strip()
```

Here is what I mean when I say it is not visible (perhaps the wrong use of the word): When I call `call_command('parse_email')` in my test file, I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_submit_bldg (bldg.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bldg/tests.py", line 36, in test_submit_bldg
      print call_command('parse_email') 
  File "django/core/management/__init__.py", line 136, in call_command
  raise CommandError("Unknown command: %r" % name)
  CommandError: Unknown command: 'parse_email'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think this code is "not visible".

Comment: When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase) in models.py and tests.py. Do you mean your parse_email() is defined out of the models.py?

Comment: Updated the question to make this more clear - see the error message I get when I call call_command('parse_email').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `parse_email` directly from your tests:

```
from somemodel.management.commands.process_email import parse_email
assert_equals(parse_email("..."), ...)
```